# Redirect database connection on PHPUnit test

Tags: php, phpunit, integration-testing

I am trying to test my PHP web with PHPUnit, and I need to test the DB connection (like insert, update and delete).
I have two databases, one for prod and one for tests. Right now I'm replacing the database URL manually before and after every test.

Is there any way to auto-replace the URLs when the code run on test mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [phpunit.xml](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html), set `bootstrap` to `bootstrap.php`:

```xml
<phpunit
 bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
>
```

Then, in `bootstrap.php`:

```php
$GLOBALS['db'] = new c_database(
 'testhost', // Host
 'testuser', // Username
 'testpass', // Password
 'testdb' // Database
);
```

You will now be able to access the database connection with `$db` from your app. In your app, you can do something like:

```php
if(!isset($db)){
 $db = new c_database(
  'livehost', // Host
  'liveuser', // Username
  'livepass', // Password
  'livedb' // Database
 );
}
```

When running tests, be sure to specify the location of `phpunit.xml`. You can do this easily with a [Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) (assuming phpunit is located at `/path/to/app/vendor/bin/phpunit` and `phpunit.xml` is located at `/path/to/app/tests/phpunit.xml`):

```
CWD:=$(PWD)

test:
    vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration $(CWD)/tests/phpunit.xml

.PHONY test
```

Now, every time you run tests (eg, `make test`), the correct credentials will be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an environment variable in `phpunit.xml`:

```
<php>
  <env name="env" value="test" />
</php>
```

And then you can set the name of the database based on the value of this environment variable:

```
$name = getenv('env') == 'test' ? 'test' : 'production';
```

Answer (score -2):

use `sed`

it is pretty much a preg replace that searches inside of files that you specify. this is how you would use it on your box

`sed -i 's/proddatabase.expensivebusiness.com/devdatabase.expemsivebusiness.com/g' *.php`

I have a shell script that goes through all prod files and puts dev labels (floating notifications, changes database addresses and replaces usernames/passwords with testing ones if necessary). make a script, put it into your bin, and just type 'dev' or 'prod' in terminal to switch between dev and prod values... unless you want have both dev and prod code in your php, then you just need to re-evaluate your approach and use simple vim preg-replace for time being.